# MySQL multiple IN clause does not work

Tags: mysql, where-in

I have a MySQL table column rubrics which contains string value '61,80,112,256'. So I try execute that query:

```
select * from table where 256 in (rubrics) and 61 in (rubrics)
```

And no result returns. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `rubrics` column is a comma separated list the `IN` operator will not work.

MySQL does have a function that can find a value in a string list so you should be able to use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select *
from yourtable
where find_in_set(61, rubrics)
  or find_in_set(256, rubrics)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/869bbe/2)

Comment: @mogilka you are welcome. If you are not able to normalize your data then this should solve your problem

Comment: Didn't know about the `FIND_IN_SET`, but looks like exactly what is required here.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `WHERE rubrics LIKE '%,256,%' OR rubrics LIKE '256,%' OR rubrics LIKE '%,256'`. Using parenthesis you can also filter on the `61`, but the resulting query will be come messy. You'd better normalize your data, so you can use subqueries and joins using keys (the real deal).

(see also bluefeet's answer as `FIND_IN_SET` is a better approach)

Comment: bouke, using like and % is less efficient. Performance is important for me. For this reason, I also do not use the benefit of JOIN string field that contains an array of integers

Comment: FWIW I have no experience with `FIND_IN_SET`, but my guess is that it will be much slower than using joins and correct use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from table where rubrics like '%'+'256,'+'%' and rubrics like '%'+'61,'+'%'
```

Comment: This also matches '1256', as the `%` will eat everything. See my answer for how `LIKE` should be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` operator does not work with strings

use correct substring matching operator like `LIKE` or `LOCATE`

one advice - update your rubics column to begin and end with `,` character, that will make your `LOCATE(",62,", rubics)` operations unambiguous as opposed to `LOCATE("62", rubics)` which will match also 622 and 262 and other combinations. Locating `,62,` wil fail if your rubics has value of `62,blah,foo,bar` because it doesn't start with `,`

Comment: Thank you, I tryed it now but using find_in_set() is more fast:
find_in_set 0.006 sec
locate 0.010 sec